# port forwarding only works with software in windows 10

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, port, forwarding

I am trying to port forward port 27015 on my computer

I've done the required tweaks on my router and firewall, and it seems I am having an issue from my computer.

Indeed, when I use "SPI port forwarder" and I open port 27015(which has firewall exception and is set on my router), canyouseeme.org says the port is opened. But when I dont use SPI port forwarder, it tells me "connection refused".

I would like not to have to use SPI fort forwarder for personal reasons.

Comment: What is SPI port forwarder? What is it forwarding to?
What is supposed to be listening on port 27015 instead of the SPI port forwarder?
What are you actually trying to do?
If canyouseeme can see the port forwarder, then your router and firewall are letting the internet access your computer on port 27015, but you say nothing about the program that you want the internet to be able to see.

Comment: I redirected port 27015 of my router to port 27015 of my computer, that's all. SPI port forwarder is a software I dont know how it works, but when I type 27015 in it (like that https://gyazo.com/ed43fc8b6420e8a1bf51087e5f992fd0) canyouseeme.org gets access to the port, while when I dont use SPI it says connection refused, but it shouldn't as I made a firewall exception. 27015 is the port to open to make a server in a video game called unturned

Comment: There are two situations that canyouseeme will report as connection refused: if the port is firewalled, or if the port is not listening for connections. The SPI program is listening for connections, and your game would also listen for connections. Have you tried running it?

Comment: didnt think of that thank you i'll try